# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Restaurant' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am facing this issue which i wanted to insert data into restaurants, but it keep showing error

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\FoodRequest; use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   public function store(FoodRequest $request)
    { 
        Restaurant  ::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->back(); 
    }
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem as if you target the `Restaurant` class, but rather, other classes. Can you `use App\Http\Controllers\Restaurant`?

Comment: Thank You So Much !!!

I am try to insert -> use App\Restaurant;

It works !! 
And thank again for your reminder. I am a beginner in Laravel 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `Restaurant` model. Models are usually under the `App` namespace.

To use your `Restaurant` mode, you must write this at the top of your controller:

```
use App\Restaurant;
```

PHP automatically looks for classes with the given name in the same namespace if it is not imported. You were looking for a class called `Restaurant` in `App\Http\Controllers`, when actually it exists in `App`

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use composer classmap. When composer loads the classmap, all classes in that folder are auto loaded. Just type hint the class name and Laravel will inject a new class instance.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/models" 
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
    }
},
```

Run `composer dump-autoload`

To inject a new class instance of your model, you have 2 options.

Inject at teh class level. The model is available to use for all methods within the class like this :

```
use Restaurant;
```

or at the method level, the model is only available to that method like this :

```
public function store(FoodRequest $request)
{ 
    \Restaurant::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back(); 
}
```

Hope this help.